# Can I see my Gmail inbox tabs as IMAP labels?

Tags: gmail, thunderbird, gmail-imap, gmail-categories

I like the new inbox tabs (categories) feature on Gmail, but it's only useful on the web interface. If I use a mail client like Thunderbird I can't see the tabs. Is there any way to give all the messages in tabs an specific IMAP label to see them from Thunderbird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There's any way to give all the messages in tabs an specific IMAP label to see them from Thunderbird?

Unfortunately, this isn't possible yet.